# Effect on vertical launch of ball from a rotating body

Tags: gravity, rotation

If a ball is launched vertically from the surface of the earth at the equator, assuming a vacuum, will the ball land in exactly the same place on the surface of the earth?  Or does the fact that the earth is rotating change the place on the surface where the ball will land?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @BobD for a small vertical launch it would land basically the same place, for a large vertical launch i am not sure

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas but in that example the ball is torqued from the top of the tower connected to earth.  if the ball starts from the ground then are you saying it would land eastward of its initial location?

Comment: Effectively yes, if the speeds, altitudes, and flight limes are low enough that you can treat the earth as an infinite flat plane with constant gravity. No, if the speeds, altitudes, and flight times are high enough that you have to deal with it as a suborbital trajectory and consider the rotation of launch point on the surface of the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Everything on earth is already accelerated to the rotation of the earth, so the ball will land where it was thrown.

Like how if you throw a ball up in a car, it does not move relative to the car as it had been accelerated to the car's velocity